# How can I make a Camel/Netty4 SSL Client initiate a handshake?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel, netty

I have a server that I wish to connect to via SSL, and then listen for data.  I have a Camel route set up (via Spring) with a Netty4 endpoint as follows:

```xml
<camel:endpoint id="sslEndpoint" uri="netty4:tcp://{{server.host}}:{{server.port}}">
  <camel:property key="clientMode" value="true" />
  <camel:property key="needClientAuth" value="true" />
  <camel:property key="sync" value="false" />
  <camel:property key="ssl" value="true" />
  <camel:property key="keyStoreResource" value="file:{{server.keystore}}" />
  <camel:property key="trustStoreResource" value="file:{{server.truststore}}" />
  <camel:property key="passphrase" value="{{server.passphrase}}" />
</camel:endpoint>
```

The route is configured in Java with this endpoint as the `from` part of the route:

```java
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("ref:sslEndpoint")
      .to("log:MyLog?level=DEBUG");
  }
}
```

By default a `from` endpoint will create a `NettyConsumer`, which acts as a server, hence specifying `clientMode=true` on the endpoint.  This is honoured when using a plain TCP connection (it does indeed connect as a client, and receive data sent to it from the server).  However, when using SSL it *doesn't* start off the SSL Handshake, meaning the server doesn't send out any data.

I have rooted through the Camel Netty4 code, and the key issue is in `DefaultServerInitializerFactory` where a new SSL Connection is configured - the `SSLEngine` has a hard-coded `setUseClientMode(false)`.  Sticking a breakpoint here and changing the call to `true` does indeed cause Netty to connect to the server, initiate the SSL handshake, and start consuming received data.

So my question is twofold:

1. How can I best resolve this issue and make the SSL Client initiate a handshake?  Have I just missed something obvious?
2. Is this a bug in Camel/Netty4, as it would appear to me that the SSL connection should honour the `clientMode` property of the endpoint?

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong here, but as you mention a from endpoint creates a consumer. This means a client will have to send an SSL request to your consumer and not force it to act as a client. A from connection implies that netty is the server. A to connection means netty is the client.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti: Yes, by default a `from` connection implies a Netty server, the documentation states that you can put the Netty Consumer into [client mode](http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html), which makes it act as a client, connecting to the server and receiving data that the server sends - this works.  But when SSL is enabled on the endpoint, the handshake isn't initiated, which from my understanding of SSL, it should be.

Comment: does the property clientMode get actually set to true? I mean do you see the value being set to true when you debug? Otherwise try setting it directly in the from() part.

Comment: Yes, `clientMode` is being set in the `NettyConfiguration` instance. When the consumer is started, the BootstrapFactory created is a `ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory` (!), which kicks off the connection to the server. But no SSL handshake occurs.

Comment: In that case report it as a bug at the Camel jira.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get someone on it :) In the meantime, I guess I'll write my own Netty Handler to sit in the encoder/decoder chain.

Comment: The issue has been reported: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10341